# 30A power connector

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, current

I've never really used power connectors before.  I am working on a project and saw there are power connectors in it.  We had some issues and changed the manufactured power connector to a 30A power connector.  The system definitely needs more than 30A.  Does the 30A really matter? Or should I buy a 60A connector instead?

Comment: The power connector has to be able to cope with the current you are drawing through it. If you don't know the current draw of your project then someone who knows what they're doing should be running the project.

Comment: I think he didn't mean to discourage you, he meant something like "if you don't get that 30A<<75A you should probably be doing something else". That thing can catch fire, injuring you or the final user. Now that's something that's worth stopping.

Comment: Excuse me, but I am not a pro electrical engineer. I am just a beginner and learning. Now I'd appreciate if you stop discouraging me and my enthusiasm of learning. Thank you @Majenko

Comment: Yes I figured it out. But thanks anyway @VladimirCravero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a power connector rated to carry *at least* the maximum current you expect it to carry.

Under the North American electrical code, it would be illegal to use a connector rated at 30 amps on a circuit where it would normally carry more than 30 amps.

Comment: Thank you... That actually fixed my problem. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Of course it matters. You need to give more information though. Current requirements, power requirements, voltage requirements, which connector you are talking about. If you pull 40A through a 30A connector there is a good chance of failure. It's also possible that nothing wrong will happen and the connector is just hotter than normal. We can't answer this without more info.

Comment: it requires 75A

Answer (score 2):

Ah, you might be able to parallel 30A pins to get higher than 30A, read the connector datasheet carefully and follow their recommendations to the letter.

Answer (score 0):

Don't parallel connectors. They are probably not designed and tested to operate in parallel. Get one connector designed for at least 75 amps.